# When uninstall the application, I don't want the SqlLite database to be deleted

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, flutter

I have an app in **Flutter**. 
When I uninstall the app, my **SqlLite** database is removed with the app. How can I solve this? I just want to remove the app, and when I reinstall the app the previous data stay there, and not get deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how it works. When the app is uninstalled all of its local data is removed too. What if the user never reinstalled your app. How long should the data stay there taking up space?

Comment: The data needs to be stored forever. Can you tell me a folder where my database may be storing and that when uninstalling the application, that folder will not be removed?

Comment: You can't do it on the device. Have you considered using a cloud technology? That's likely your only option

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, but I am perfectly aware of other apps that have the capability of storing files in "external storage".  Even [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) explains that this is an option.  Perhaps cloud storage would be a better options.  Perhaps one really needs to consider the implications of doing this.  But the other comments are knee-jerk answers based on best-practices, etc., not technical answers.  Even if there are good reasons for app isolation, answers like "oh, what happens when it takes up space" are not useful.

Comment: Best option is to consider an external source. as @LuisGustavoSouza said cloud would be the best. Try firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a way to do that on Android devices...

```
<manifest ... >
        ...
        <application android:allowBackup="true" ... >
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

this will keep all data on your device and will be restored after reinstall.